# What exactly the use SQL in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have just started studying SAS and a little bit confused. This link [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sas/sas_sql.htm) show a Query to the DATA SET. I thought that it would be like connecting to a external DATABASE and perform a request query to a DATABASE.
So does the DATA SET is the database and the SQL syntax is just another way of processing data in the DATA SET?
Also can you recommend a better tutorial. A free open source tutorial/book/sources will be much better.

Well I'm still learning and I will appreciate any opinion/answer/recommendation.

I use SAS University Edition in virtually in my computer.

Comment: Coursera has a free SAS e-course and SAS has two on it's website. Lexjansen.com has tutorials on any topics you can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So does the DATA SET is the database and the SQL syntax is just another way of processing data in the DATA SET?

DATA SET is the table (*not the database*), and yes SQL is another way.

You can think of the **native** SAS library engine, `V9` as the data base. For example:

```
libname mydata          'c:\projectx\sasdata';  is the same as
libname mydata V9       'c:\projectx\sasdata';
libname mydata <engine> 'c:\projectx\sasdata';
libname mydata <engine> <options for connection parameters>;
```

`V9` is the default engine used when the libname statement does specify one. There are different engines for connecting to almost any remote (non-SAS) data bases, data files or data providers that let a SAS coder code in `SAS` and not have to learn the language or dialect of the remote environment.

A rough mapping of SAS structure concepts to data base concepts:

- V9 engine ~ "data base"
- local folder ~ schema, instance, or catalog
- data set ~ table
- variable ~ column
- observation ~ row

You can learn more about engines by searching the help system for "SAS Engines" and "How Engines Work with SAS Files"

`Proc SQL` lets you code using SQL.  A coder can choose the best language for themselves and for the problem at hand; be it `SQL`, `DATA` steps and `PROC` steps.

Answer (score 2):

Do not confuse SQL (query language) with mySQL, postgresql, sqlite or any other database technology.

proc sql is an alternative to the data step.

Mostly you can do the same with both, but one might be able to perform better in certain situation or allow for easier/shorter syntax than the other.

The dataset you use has nothing to do with the language you use to "query" it.

Look into `LIBNAME` statement to connect to external databases.

Answer (score 2):

As someone said before, do not confuse between SQL (the query language) and DataSet (its the name of the tables in SAS).
Here is an example of the same result using DATA SET syntax and PROC SQL syntax:

With DATA SET:

```
DATA myNewTable;
    SET myTable;
    WHERE id = 123;
RUN;
```

With PROC SQL syntax:

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE myNewTable AS
       SELECT * FROM myTable
       WHERE id = 123;
QUIT;
```

Hope it makes sense.